# LibreOffice Dialog Not working as intended

Tags: vba, dialog, libreoffice

I have been trying to do this myself, but I just dont know how to define the problem. I have been writing a Macro for LibreOffice and it includes several dialogs. When I Run the macro I want to execute a Function after the dialog is visiable. I could not find the solution to this so I made another dialog which only shows "Loading, Wait..." and I inserted at the beggining and end of that function, dialog.Execute() and dialog.endExecute(). I guess the program stops at .execute() and im stuck at "Loading, Wait..." sign if I press "X" in the corner the program continues normally.

Best solution would be if I could run a function after the dialog is visible. So is there sort of a trigger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the dialog and make it visible, but this would not activate the functions (buttons etc.), as this is what `execute` does

```
' StarBasic
' Tools
With GlobalScope.BasicLibraries
   If ( Not .isLibraryLoaded("Tools") ) Then
     .LoadLibrary( "Tools" )
   End If
End With 

sampleDialog = LoadDialog( "Standard", "Dialog1")

sampleDialog.setVisible(TRUE)
```

Does this help you?

Comment: I tought about it but it still doesn't do what I need it to do, I would need to execute a specific function that i have written, as soon as the dialog pop's up. Like in excel ther is a OnExecute() Function that runs as soon as the program starts.

Comment: I am not aware of such a function, i think you have to rebuild it, using `setVisible` (as shown above), then run whatever you need, finally `execute` dialog

Comment: I figured it out! ... I forgot to think aoutside of the box ;) I changed the dialog so all was disabled and in huge red letters wrote "LOADING" after the function ran i enabled everything and changed loading to ready,  ran execute and that's it :) Thank you !